# Extracting counts of booleans by year and months

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
id   timestamp     alive
 1   2019-10-10    true
 2   2019-10-10    false
...  .........    .....
 N   2021-01-01    boolean
```

**What I need:**

Extract **by year and month** how many `true` and `false` and the relation `false/true` the table has.  Like this:

```
 Period    True  False  false/true
 JAN-2019  1000   10      0.01
```

**What I tried:**

I did some `cte` using `date_trunc` but I got so many fails that I gave up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `FILTER` clause for each condition (alive and not alive) and then aggregate it by the formatted timestamp using `to_char`, e.g.

```
SELECT 
  to_char(timestamp,'MON-YYYY'),
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE alive) AS "true",
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE NOT alive) AS "false",
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE NOT alive)::numeric * 1.0 / 
    nullif(count(*) FILTER (WHERE alive),0)::numeric AS "false/true"
FROM t
GROUP BY to_char(timestamp,'MON-YYYY');
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e63dc5cd5beeab7e78d8572fe3efa54d)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```sql
with agg as (
    select cnv."Period"
          ,sum(case when     alive then 1        end) as "True"
          ,sum(case when not alive then 1 else 0 end) as "False"
    from (values                           -- vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
         (1,'2019-10-10'::date, true ) -- replace this values()
        ,(2,'2019-10-10'      , false) -- table with your
        ,(3,'2021-01-01'      , false) -- actual table
         ) dat(id,"timestamp",alive)       -- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
         cross join lateral (select to_char(dat."timestamp",'YYYY-MM')) cnv("Period")
    group by cnv."Period"
)
select *
      ,("False" * 1.0 / "True")::numeric(10,2) as "false/true"
from agg
order by "Period"
;
```

- The lateral join just **c**o**nv**erts the date to `yyyy-mm` format once, so the result can be referenced multiple times
- The CTE counts the number of true & false once, so the results can be referenced in the ratio calculation.  Note that by leaving out the `else` on the `case` statements, the `sum()` will return `null` for periods in which there are no occurrences of `true`.  The ratio will then show `null` rather than produce a divide by zero error
- The ratio calculation multiplies the integer value by a `numeric` value to avoid integer division rounding.  It then casts the result to a numeric type with 2 decimal places.